# how to use IN in WHERE claus doctrine 2 using querybuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm

How can I use IN in WHERE claus in doctrine2 using [querybuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

How can I convert following sql in doctrine using querybuilder?

```
SELECT fooid FROM foo WHERE bar IN ('A','C');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is included in the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class).

Assuming `$qb` is your query builder:

```
$qb->add('select', new Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Select(array('Foo.fooid')))
    ->add('from', new Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\From('Foo'))
    ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('Foo.bar', '?1'))
    ->setParameter(1, array('A', 'C'));
```

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Main\Controller\Expr\Select' not found in /home/websites/site/module/Main/src/Main/Controller/xxxxxController.php on line 57 - I am using ZF2, Do I need to add any library?

Comment: No, but `Expr\Select` is relative to your current namespace, which seems to be `Main\Controller`. Use a fully qualified name instead: `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Select`.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be written using

```
$qb->select('Foo.fooid')
           ->from('Foo')
           ->where($qb->expr()->in('Foo.bar', '?1'))      
           ->setParameters(array(1 => array('A', 'C')));
```

or as Guillaume mentioned above

```
$qb = $objectManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->add('select', new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Select(array('Foo.fooid')))
        ->add('from', new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\From('Foo'))
        ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('Foo.bar', '?1'))
        ->setParameter(1, array('A', 'C'));
```